# JMS queue connection factory in struts

Tags: tomcat, jms, struts

I'm trying to integrate JMS message sender in a struts based web application. I have defined the message sender in a method and called the method in actionForm's execute method. The error i get is

```
javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name queueConnectionFactory is not bound in this Context
```

I guess the error is at this place

```
 try {
    connectionFactory = (ConnectionFactory)jndiContext.lookup("queueConnectionFactory");
    destination = (Destination)jndiContext.lookup(destinationName);
} catch (NamingException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    System.exit(1);
}
```

I'am using ActiveMQ as the Message broker.

Comment: The other thing about the application is, after executing the tomcat gets shutdown automatically and i get error on webpage i.e unable to connect...

Answer (score 2):

In the web layer you have to use full JNDI name of the conn. factory, i.e. `java:comp/env/queueConnectionFactory`.

In Tomcat, you also need to declare it in the `web.xml`:

```xml
<resource-ref id="ResourceRef_0">
   <description>Logical mapping of QueueConnectionFactory</description>
   <res-ref-name>queueConnectionFactory</res-ref-name>
   <res-type>javax.jms.QueueConnectionFactory</res-type>
   <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
   <res-sharing-scope>Shareable</res-sharing-scope>
</resource-ref>
```